# How do I access DOM elements of an embedded template? (Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular2-template, viewchild

**Context**

I have two Angular Components, a parent and a child. The parent passes an optional `<ng-template>` TemplateRef to the child as an `@Input`. The child then either renders this template or renders its default template if no input was given.

**parent.component.html**

```
// Pass in template as @Input 
<child [customTemplate]="parentTemplate"></child> 

// Define Custome Template 
<ng-template #parentTemplate>
   <div #container class="container">HELLO FROM CUSTOM CONTAINER</div>
</ng-template>
```

**child.component.html**

```
// Render correct template
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplate || defaultTemplate;"> 
</ng-container>

// Define default template 
<ng-template #defaultTemplate>
  <div #container class="container">HELLO FROM DEFAULT CONTAINER</div>
</ng-template>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() public customTemplate!: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>
  @ViewChild("container")
  containerRef!: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.containerRef?.nativeElement.offsetWidth)
  }
}
```

**The Issue**

I'd like to be able to access DOM Elements rendered by my child component. For example, say I want to find the width of an HTML Element currently rendered on screen.

If I define a template variable `#container` in both the customTemplate & the defaultTemplate, and then try to access that element using `@ViewChild('container)` or `ContentChild('container)`, it returns undefined on the customTemplate but returns the correct Element Reference with the default.

How do I access these embedded DOM elements, regardless of whether or not the template is passed in as an `@Input` or if we use the default?

Check out the Stackblitz below for an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Hopefully it'll be self-explanatory.

[Stackblitz Example with full project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2sema2?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code and I am using only a child component instead of two like your example, in my solution I used ternary operator to decide which template I need to render.

[My solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l86j5z?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

`app.componen.ts`

```html
<!-- Call to Child Component -->
<div class="childComponent">
  <child [customTemplate]="displayCustom ? parentTemplate : null"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! this just displays the width from within the template though. I don't have access to the element from the child component, do I? What if I wanted to do some form of calculation with that value? or what if I don't want to display it at all and just want it saved as a variable?